# Can't use query function in migration

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to make a simple `SELECT` request in a migration file in JavaScript with Sequelize.

with this code:

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const { query, QueryTypes } = use_env_variable
  ? new Sequelize(process.env[use_env_variable], config)
  : new Sequelize(database, username, password, config);

module.exports = {
  up: async ({ addColumn, removeColumn }, { INTEGER }) => (
    const results = await query("SELECT * FROM table;", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
  ),
  down: async () => {}
});
```

I'm getting stuck with the error:

> ERROR: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

meanwhile, if i don't specifically import only `query` and `QueryTypes` from sequelize and use the conventionnal `sequelize.query` or `sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT` it will works:

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = use_env_variable
  ? new Sequelize(process.env[use_env_variable], config)
  : new Sequelize(database, username, password, config);

module.exports = {
  up: async ({ addColumn, removeColumn }, { INTEGER }) => (
    const results = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM table;", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
  ),
  down: async () => {}
});
```

the code above works fine in the way I need, but why ? If I mix both code in order to have `sequelize.query` and `query` like importing like that:

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = use_env_variable
  ? new Sequelize(process.env[use_env_variable], config)
  : new Sequelize(database, username, password, config);
const { query, QueryTypes } = use_env_variable
  ? new Sequelize(process.env[use_env_variable], config)
  : new Sequelize(database, username, password, config);
```

I figured myself that `console.log(query === sequelize.query);` would return `true` but using `query` instead of `sequelize.query` will provoke the `ERROR: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined` error...

where did i do something wrong ?

Comment: Why do you try to instantiate a connection inside a migration? Just use `.sequelizrc` along with `config`-file in the JSON-format and indicate the required config for DB using NODE_ENV

Comment: @Anatoly I've taken account your comment but it's not quite relevant to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from the sequelize' Slack answered me:

> It's normal. `query` is a method that needs to know the instance it's being called on. If you extract it from the sequelize instance, its `this` will be undefined instead of the sequelize instance
> you can do this though:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
const { QueryTypes } = sequelize;
const query = sequelize.query.bind(sequelize);
```